# How to add parent frame map? Map not exists

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Map frame never exist before.
I broadcast map -> odom when init node. When i use frameExists, map frame not exists. But in rqt_tf_tree it exists and connected to odom.
Where can be problem?

```
    self.tf_broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
    self.tf_listener = tf.TransformListener()

    self.tf_broadcaster.sendTransform((5.0, 3.0, 0.0),
        tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        rospy.Time.now(),
        "odom",
        "map")
    
    #This condition never True. 
    if self.tf_listener.frameExists("odom") and self.tf_listener.frameExists("map"):
        rospy.loginfo("transform exist!")
        t = self.tf_listener.getLatestCommonTime("odom", "map")
        position, quaternion = self.tf_listener.lookupTransform("odom", "map", t)
        print position, quaternion
        print("!!!!!!!!!")
```

**Edit 1:**

Main goal of my node to improve robot localization odometry based on imu and encoders. I calculated new position of robot in map frame. And want somehow to transform odometry frame respect to map frame.

My actual [global localization node](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wX9sW6dvg89QDaT2eM9TioexWEWQf0aC), where i want to use tf.

[Bag file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w-BLJCpELCieLq_ok5hp7QpvscMaJ7fr) in which I test my node.

Output of rqt_tf_tree.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302217/how-to-add-parent-frame-map?-map-not-exists./) by [Stepan Kostusiev](https://answers.ros.org/users/36328/stepan-kostusiev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be broadcasting before your listener is fully initialized. Have you tried adding waits?

That said, this is a strange usage pattern. If you publish the frames continuously from other nodes, do you have the same problem?

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stepan Kostusiev](https://answers.ros.org/users/36328/stepan-kostusiev/) on 2018-09-05**:
Thank you for answer. I try to add waits and broadcast this transform from other node, but it is no effect.
I add my node code and bag file. Maybe it will more clear understand problem.